# Difference between referrer="never" and rel="noreferrer"

Tags: html

I was wondering what the difference is between:

`<a href="example.com" referrer="never">Link</a>`

and

`<a href="example.com" rel="noreferrer">Link</a>`

I want it so when a user clicks an external link on my site no referrer data is sent to that site. When I search for that on Google it seems `rel="noreferrer"` is the way to go however I believe https://dereferer.me (common website for doing exactly this to indivual links) uses `referrer="never".`

***Follow-up Question***

What's the difference between:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

and

```
<meta name="referrer" content="never">
```

and

```
<meta name="referrer" content="none">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Given a string token (for example, the value of a referrer directive), this algorithm will return the referrer policy it refers to:
> If token is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the strings "never" or "no-referrer", return No Referrer.
> If token is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "origin", return Origin.
> If token is ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "default" or "no-referrer-when-downgrade", return No Referrer When Downgrade.
> If token is ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "origin-when-cross-origin", return Origin When Cross-Origin.
> If token is ASCII case-insensitive match for the strings "always" or "unsafe-url", return Unsafe URL.
> Return No Referrer.
> Note: Authors are encouraged to avoid the legacy keywords never, default, and always. The keywords no-referrer, no-referrer-when-downgrade, and unsafe-url respectively are preferred.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec/blob/848779239bd30de8ec7943858db2e8fb6bba9328/specs/referrer-policy/index.html)

> If value is one of the values given in the first column of the following table, then set value to the value given in the second column:

> Legacy value  Referrer policy
> never no-referrer
> default   the default referrer policy
> always    unsafe-url
> origin-when-crossorigin   origin-when-cross-origin

[enter link description here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-referrer)

So I think "never" = "no-referrer".

---

> Note: Authors are encouraged to avoid the legacy keywords never,
> default, and always. The keywords none, none-when-downgrade, and
> unsafe-url respectively are preferred.

[enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-referrer-policy-20140807/)

So I think "never" = "none".

---

**"never" = "no-referrer" = "none" = "noreferrer"**

In addition, I guess chromium doesn't support "none", I don't see "none" here.
[enter link description here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/web_tests/http/tests/security/)

Comment: Welcome!  just a comment: formatting and proofreading answers goes a long way... see [answer].